# Difference between Past Simple and Past Continuous for a past action

Tags: simple-past

Should the gaps in this sentence be filled with verbs in Past Simple or Past Continuous tense?

_______________ you ___________________ (make) a lot of friends when you ________________ (live) abroad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended ways of writing this:

*"Did you make a lot of friends when you lived abroad?"*

*"Have you made a lot of friends while living abroad?"* (Present perfect — suggests that you may still be living abroad, or at least close temporal proximity to this time.)

*"Had you made a lot of friends while living abroad, before coming home?"*

I find that is reads awkwardly when you use the past perfect without it being clear that it's entirely enclosed within the past. I felt compelled to add the clarification to the last example for it to read comfortably. I would advise avoiding it when there are alternatives, such as the versions above.